# Greater than and less than function in pandas

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, conditional-statements

I am testing out data within a column 'daychange'. If the values are within a range I want a separate column to display 100 for yes and 0 for no. I tried this code:

```
cond16 = df[(df['daychange']<8) & (df['daychange']>2)]
df['day3'] = np.where(cond16, 100, 0)
```

But get the following error:

```
ValueError: Length of values (932) does not match length of index (13063)
```

Little help will be dearly appreciated!

Comment: You already selecting the data, just use the conditions: `cond16 = (df['daychange']<8) & (df['daychange']>2)`

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Erfan in the comment you've already created the filter. Just use that to set the values in the DataFrame.

```
# Create filter condition
cond16 = (df['daychange']<8) & (df['daychange']>2)

# Set rows where condition is true to 100
df.loc[cond16, 'day3'] = 100

# Set rows where condition is not true to 0
df.loc[~cond16, 'day3'] = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it. The little error is mentioned at comments by @Erfan. You just need the condition, not the selection in the `np.where`.

```
cond16 = (df['daychange']<8) & (df['daychange']>2)
df['day3'] = np.where(cond16, 100, 0)
```